# Error in Sandman when using Postgres DB

Tags: python, api, rest

I am trying to make an API and tried using the Wrapper made by Jeff Knupp (thanks for the awesome book). Anyways, Sandman as it is called is not really useful to me at the moment. This is what I am trying to do:

```
from sandman import app
import psycopg2

app.config[
   'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql+psycopg2://user:pw@ec2-54-235-245-180.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d1hvkbpmj6bpqu'

from sandman.model import activate

activate()

app.run()
```

The response I am getting is the following:

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|schema_migrations|schema_migrations could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'schema_migrations'

Comment: Fixed it, what you need to do is add a primary key to every column in the database that you are trying to run sandman on . This then straight opens a new browser window and will show you all of the tables in your database (and model). So this seems to work like a charm

Comment: So always(!) make sure you have a primary in your tables when using Sandman!